# How calculate additional column with percentage to the total in Tableau?

Tags: pivot-table, tableau-api, percentage

I could create something like pivot table for my statistic. Here is an example:

[image]

But I need to add statistic like in this table:

[image]

Here is a link to data: [Data for the Question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0408y7zxm6uvc0/QuestionT%20-%20Copy.xlsx?dl=0)

How calculate additional column with percentage to the total and total percentage as separate column to the pivot table in Tableau?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data look different from your screenshot. But generally you can use a table calculation to achieve this.
[image]

Right click on the measure you want to add table calculation and select "Add Table calculation". Make sure that calculation type is "Percent of Total " and Compute using is "Table(Down)".

[image]
[image]